# Ajax Загрузка Пагинация

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть Код на Jquery

```
jQuery(function($){
NggAjaxNavigation = {
    loading_image:            null,

    /**
     * Initializes the AJAX paginators
     */
    init:                     function(){
        var self = this;
        $('body').on('click', 'a.page-numbers, a.prev, a.next', function(e){
          var $this     = $(this);
          var $gallery  = $this.parents('.ngg-galleryoverview:first');
          var gallery_id= $gallery.attr('id').replace('ngg-gallery-','').replace(/-\d+$/, '');

          if ($gallery.hasClass('ngg-ajax-pagination-none'))
            return;

          e.preventDefault();

          self.toggle_busy(true);

          $.get($this.attr('href'), function(response){
              var html = $(response);
              $gallery.replaceWith(html.find('div[id*="ngg-gallery-'+gallery_id+'"]'));
              $("div").append("<div>hello world</div>")


              // Let the user know that we've refreshed the content
              $(document).trigger('refreshed');


          }).always(function() {
              self.toggle_busy(false);
          });
        });
    },

    /**
     * Gets the querystring parameters for a url
     * @param url
     * @return {Object}
     */
    get_querystring_params_from_url: function(url){
        var url_params = {};
        var url_parts = url.split('?');
        if (url_parts.length == 2) {
            url_parts = url_parts[1].split('&');
            for (var key in url_parts) {
                var param = url_parts[key].split('=');
                url_params[param[0]] = param.length == 2 ? param[1] : '';
            }
        }
        return url_params;
    },


    toggle_busy:                    function(busy) {
        $('body, a').css('cursor', busy ? 'wait' : 'auto');
    }
};

NggAjaxNavigation.init();
```

});

Я хочу что бы пагинация работала следующим образом.
Я нажимаю кнопку
И новая  страница пагинации загружаться внизу Блока, а верхний блок остаётся, сейчас же
Всё работает так: я нажимаю (следующую страницу) и моя первая заменяется следующей...
Помогите в Jquery я нуб

Answer (score 1):

jQuery(function($){
    NggAjaxNavigation = {
        loading_image:            null,

```
    /**
     * Initializes the AJAX paginators
     */
    init:                     function(){
        var self = this;
        $('body').on('click', 'a.page-numbers, a.prev, a.next', function(e){
          var $this     = $(this);
          var $gallery  = $this.parents('.ngg-galleryoverview:first');
          var gallery_id= $gallery.attr('id').replace('ngg-gallery-','').replace(/-\d+$/, '');

          if ($gallery.hasClass('ngg-ajax-pagination-none'))
            return;

          e.preventDefault();


          $.get($this.attr('href'), function(response){
              var html = $(response);
              $gallery;
              $gallery.clone().appendTo('#main').replaceWith(html.find('div[id*="ngg-gallery-'+gallery_id+'"]'));
              // Let the user know that we've refreshed the content
              $(document).trigger('refreshed');


          }).always(function() {
              self.toggle_busy(false);
          });
        });
    },

    /**
     * Gets the querystring parameters for a url
     * @param url
     * @return {Object}
     */
    get_querystring_params_from_url: function(url){
        var url_params = {};
        var url_parts = url.split('?');
        if (url_parts.length == 2) {
            url_parts = url_parts[1].split('&');
            for (var key in url_parts) {
                var param = url_parts[key].split('=');
                url_params[param[0]] = param.length == 2 ? param[1] : '';
            }
        }
        return url_params;
    },


    toggle_busy:                    function(busy) {
        $('body, a').css('cursor', busy ? 'wait' : 'auto');
    }
};

NggAjaxNavigation.init();
```

});

Я решил этот вопрос)
Таким способом, для меня это сработало